# Why do Scala's index methods return -1 instead of None if the element is not found?

Tags: scala

I've always been wondering why in Scala the various index methods for determining the position of an element in a collection (e.g. `List.indexOf`, `List.indexWhere`) return `-1` to indicate the absence of the given element in the collection, instead of a more idiomatic `Option[Int]`. Is there some particular advantage to returning `-1` instead of `None`, or is this just for historical reasons?

Comment: My guess is a combination of historical reasons (ie Java) and the fact that indices are rarely used in Scala so people don't pay as much attention to these functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is just for historical reasons, but then one wants to know what the historical reasons are: what was the history, and why did it turn out that way?

The immediate history is the `java.lang.String.indexOf` method, which returns the index, or -1 if no matching character is found.  But this is hardly new; the Fortran SCAN function returns 0 if no character is found in a string, which is the same thing given that Fortran uses 1-indexing.

The reason to do this is that strings have only positive length, so any negative length can be used as a `None` value without any overhead of boxing.  `-1` is the most convenient negative number, so that's it.

And this can add up if the compiler isn't smart enough to realize that all the boxing and unboxing and everything is irrelevant.  In particular, an object creation tends to take 5-10 ns, while a function call or comparison typically takes more like 1-2 ns, so if the collection is short, creating a new object can have a sizable fractional penalty (more so if your memory is already taxed and the GC has a lot of work to do).

If Scala had initially had an amazing optimizer, then the choice probably would have been different, as one would just write things with options, which is safer and less of a special case, and then trust the compiler to convert it into appropriately high-performance code.

Answer (score 1):

Speed? (not sure)

```
def a(): Option[Int] = Some(Math.random().toInt)
def b(): Int = Math.random().toInt
val t0 = System.nanoTime; (0 to 1000000).foreach(_ => a()); println("" + (System.nanoTime - t0))
// 53988000
val t0 = System.nanoTime; (0 to 1000000).foreach(_ => b()); println("" + (System.nanoTime - t0))
// 49273000
```

And you also should always check for index < 0 in `Some(index)`

Comment: Your example and the text below it is confusing because when it's done right Some does not contain a value < 0, instead None is returned.

Comment: `Some` can actually contain a value < 0, why not. That's the main cause of confusion - should I check for `None`, and also for `index < 0`, when using `Option`?

Comment: No, Some must not contain a value < 0, at least not in that context (since it is not a valid value). The question was why the Option monad is not used and not if it makes sense to wrap the return value of the function in a Some (as you did in your code example).

Comment: `Math.random` is relatively expensive, which is why the overhead here looks small.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the benefit that just returning an `Int` can use Java's built-in types, whereas `Option[Int]` would need to wrap the integer in an `Object`. This means both worse speed (as indicated by @idonnie) but also more memory usage.

While `Option` is great as a general tool (and I use it a lot) also other non-value presentations s.a. `Double.NaN` or an empty string are perfectly valid, and useful.

One of the benefits of using `Option` is the ability to pass it to `for` loops etc. as a collection. If you are not likely to do that, checking for -1 or `NaN` may be more concise than doing matches for `None`/`Some`.

Comment: Scala doesn't have a for loop, it has a for comprehension, which btw. doesn't operate on collections but on monads.